# can't connecting to mysqli php What's wrong there

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cms'); 

if($connection){
  echo "Error : unable to connect to mysqli.".PHP_EOL;
  echo "Debugging errno".mysqli_connect_errno().PHP_EOL;
  echo "Debugging error".mysqli_connect_error().PHP_EOL;
  exit;
}
?>
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Error : unable to connect to mysqli. Debugging errno0 Debugging error

Comment: Your logic is wrong - you could check for `if (mysqli_connect_errno())` instead. Your current logic prints that you have an error when you don't - its inverted.

Answer (score 0):

Brother your connection is successful , you just need to use -

if(!$connection) instead of if($connection)